# When invoking .NET CLR from within C++, an error is returned

Tags: c++

I am calling a .NET assembly from C++.

This works perfectly for any test .NET 4.0 projects that I call.

However, when calling a large project with 20 sub-assemblies, it fails with the error below:

```
Failed to execute assembly: 0x80004003. GetLastError=126. dwReturn=1.
```

Here is the C++ code that generates the error:

```
DWORD dwReturn;
hr = pCLR->ExecuteInDefaultAppDomain(szApplication, szEntryType, szEntryMethod, szParameter, &dwReturn);
if (FAILED(hr))
{
    // Fails if I try the production assembly, with 20 subassemblies.
    printf("    Failed to execute assembly: 0x%X. GetLastError=%d. dwReturn=%d.\n", hr, GetLastError(), dwReturn);
}
else
{
    // Works 100% if I plug in a small toy assembly in .NET 4.0.
    wprintf(L"    Assembly returned: %d\n", dwReturn);
}
```

### Environment

- Visual Studio 2010 SP1.
- C++ for the code above.
- .NET 4.0 for the target assembly.

Comment: FYI: 126 means "The specified module could not be found.".  0x80004003 means "Invalid pointer"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your managed code died with a NullReferenceException.  Its Exception.HResult value is 0x80004003, E_POINTER.

Clearly that's a very common reason for managed code to die.  In the transition from managed code back to native code, you'll lose a lot of context for the exception.  That puts a burden on the managed code to do some essential error logging, at least the all-mighty Exception.StackTrace.  The .NET 4 AppDomain.FirstChanceException event can be useful.

Debug the problem by enabling managed code debugging, Project + Properties, Debugging, Debugger Type = Mixed.  And Debug + Exceptions, Thrown checkbox for CLR exceptions so the debugger stops the program when the exception is thrown.

Comment: Thanks! I think if I turn on options for debugging managed code in the original C++ project (as per your instructions), and debugging unmanaged code in the C# project (under "Debug"), then I should be able to step from C++ >> C# >> C++.

Comment: No, stepping does not work.  Use the Debug + Exceptions dialog as I described.

Comment: Absolutely brilliant! This brought up the *exact* line of code that the .NET app was stumbling over (it was calling "System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location()").

Comment: I gotta say - you are truly a God among Programmers.